# Can we share/export the report templates in GA4? Is there any way to do that?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have created custom reports in GA4 & now I want to export/share the template of that report without data so that other people need not to create the reports again like adding dimensions & metrics. Is there any option to do that?